# Django IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: django

I keep getting the following error when trying to submit my form?

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_query.course_id
```

The following is my `query_create` view:

```
def query_create(request, course_pk,step_pk):   #what course this quiz belongs to
    text = get_object_or_404(models.Text, course_id=course_pk, pk=step_pk)
    form = forms.QueryForm()  #create blank form

    if request.method == 'POST':
         logging.error('Inside Post.....................................................................')
         form = forms.QueryForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             query = form.save(commit=False)  #dont put anything in daabase make model quiz instance
             #query.course = course
             query.text = text
             query.save()

             messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                             "Quiz Added!")
             return HttpResponseRedirect(query.get_absolute_url())
    return render (request,'courses/query_form.html', {'form':form , 'text': text})
```

The following is my Query model:

```
class Query(Step):
    times = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null=True)
    feedback = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('courses:query', kwargs={
            'course_pk': self.course_id,
            'step_pk': self.id
        })
```

Comment: `null=True` on model fields is generally rare, are you sure you need it?

Comment: Looks to me like your models and your database are out of sync. Like you used to have a `course` foreign key on `Query` and now you don't? Did you migrate your database to reflect your model changes?

Comment: Ye when i do my make migration and migrate everything is ok.